# Python: How can I change a UTC timestamp from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp, datetime-format

I cant seem to change a UTC timestamp format in python.
The dates are in the following format (They are in an excel sheet)

**UTC EVENT TIMESTAMP**

1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM

1/22/2021 8:47:52 AM

I am trying to use the following piece of code but it keeps saying that the format doesn't match

```
string_col = str(df[' UTC Event Timestamp'])
string_col.strip()

t = datetime.strptime(string_col, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
dt_to_string = t.strftime('%d/%m%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print(dt_to_string)
```

Comment: Did you miss a slash(`/`)? `'%d/%m%Y %I:%M:%S %p'` -> `'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S"%p'`

Comment: it seems you're working with `pandas`, have a look at [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: @SayandipDutta you are right, I did miss a slash but I keep getting the same ValueError UTC Event Timestamp, Length: 387, dtype: object' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'

Comment: @MrFuppes I just tried to use pd.to_datetime but it gave me the following error:       File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 649, in parse raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 0        1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and it works. I am using python 3.6. Which version do you use?

Comment: @mosc9575 I am using 3.8.2

Comment: could you add exemplary content of `df[' UTC Event Timestamp']`? It seems to contains timestamp strings that need to be "cleanded" before parsing to datetime...

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) on your dataframe:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(["1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM", "1/22/2021 8:47:52 AM"])
>>> s

0    1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM
1    1/22/2021 8:47:52 AM
dtype: object

>>> t = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> t

0   2021-01-22 08:45:28
1   2021-01-22 08:47:52
dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> t.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

0    22/01/2021 08:45:28 AM
1    22/01/2021 08:47:52 AM
dtype: object
```

Your problem isn't the format, it is `str(col)`. To convert a column to string you call [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html), if you call `str` it no longer remains a `Series` or `df`, for example:

```
>>> s

0    1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM
1    1/22/2021 8:47:52 AM
dtype: object

>>> str(s)

'0    1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM\n1    1/22/2021 8:47:52 AM\ndtype: object'
```

^ This would not work with `datetime.datetime.strptime`.

Your code works for a single value:

```
>>> s
0    1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM
1    1/22/2021 8:47:52 AM

>>> s[0]
'1/22/2021 8:45:28 AM'

>>> datetime.strptime(s[0], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 22, 8, 45, 28)

>>> datetime.strptime(s[0], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
'22/01/2021 08:45:28 AM'
```

If you want non leading zero-padded format, use:

```
# On Windows (use '%#m' instead of '%m')
>>> datetime.strptime(s[0], '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%d/%#m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
'22/1/2021 08:45:28 AM'

# On Linux (use '%-m' instead of '%m')
>>> datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%d/%-m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
'22/1/2021 08:45:28 AM'
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly but when I introduce the UTC Event Timestamp column from my dataframe I keep getting the same error Name:  UTC Event Timestamp, Length: 387, dtype: object' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' (match). I used strip() in order to get rid of a space that was before every entry, but still doesn't work.  I am building the dataframe from the read_excel() function

Comment: do you think you could write the whole code by transforming the column to a string? I am still having the same issue