# Python: How to change a UTC timestamp from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to change the format of a UTC timestamp in a csv file but nothing seems to be working.
It keeps saying that there is a ValueError `does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'`
Below there is an example of the CSV column

[Example of CSV column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdd32.png)

```
df[' UTC Event Timestamp'] = df[' UTC Event Timestamp'].astype(str)
string_col = str(df)
string_col.strip()

datetime.strptime(string_col, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
datetime.strptime(string_col, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

print(string_col)
```

Comment: Please provide your traceback too.

Comment: Please don't re-post your questions; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874039/python-how-can-i-change-a-utc-timestamp-from-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-to-dd-mm-yy#comment116476632_65874039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
df['string_col'].apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(row, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

to convert the column in to datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['UTC Event Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTC Event Timestamp'])
df['UTC Event Timestamp'] = df['UTC Event Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
```