# Python: pandas.DataFrame.to_csv is not populating the output column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, export-to-csv

I have the following code that is basically changing the format of a UTC timestamp from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM. It is working fine but now I need it to either replace the old column in the same csv file or create another csv file but with the modified date format.
The thing is that when I run the code the UTC timestamp column is empty, it has the header though.

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/javie/OneDrive/Escritorio/22.1.21_P1_English_Language_Y10.csv")

df[' UTC Event Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[' UTC Event Timestamp'])
df[' UTC Event Timestamp'] = df[' UTC Event Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: print(x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')))

df.to_csv("C:/Users/javie/OneDrive/Escritorio/output.csv",index=False,date_format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Comment: you are using the `print` function in you lambda function . . .

Comment: @Javier you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886069/python-how-to-change-a-utc-timestamp-from-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-am-to-dd-mm-yyyy/65886217#65886217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost there.
The usage of `print()` is not necessary, that is where your problem comes from.

Remove that and your code should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/javie/OneDrive/Escritorio/22.1.21_P1_English_Language_Y10.csv")

df[' UTC Event Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[' UTC Event Timestamp'])
df[' UTC Event Timestamp'] = df[' UTC Event Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))

df.to_csv("C:/Users/javie/OneDrive/Escritorio/output.csv",index=False,date_format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```